# Migrating Websphere Application Server 7 BASE edition to 8.5 BASE edition issue using migration.sh

Tags: websphere

we have tested WAS 7 migration into 8.5 by using the migration.sh script and everything seemed to go fine but we have lost the graphical management of the servers and applications (not of the AdminAgent: that works fine).

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Usually prior to getting to this screen

[image]

you need to choose between

[image]

Well, as a consequence of our mistaken migration we now access directly to the above one, i.e. waspro1ANode01 (Admin Agent) but have lost the other one and all our trials to recover it have been unsuccessful.

Please, any help is most welcome !!!

Comment: What happens when you try to register the server to the admin agent again? I found this about how to do it using the command line https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tagt_adminagent_setup.html

Comment: lwestby, thank you very much for your comment. It did the work  !!  We registered the node to the admin agent again following your link and it worked that easy. Again, thank you VERY VERY MUCH !!!! Best regards from Spain.